# How to assign an object from an array to a variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I'm trying to assign an object from an array, that array will always have 1 object because I have filtered it out when I call the function.

I have my `currentAccount: UserAccount[];` array which I know for sure that there is only a single object of type `UserAccount`. I am trying to assign that single object to a variable object `account: UserAccount;` itself instead of leaving it as an array. This is my `account.component.ts`:

```
currentUser: User;
currentAccount: UserAccount[];
account: UserAccount;

constructor(
  private alertService: AlertService,
  private userService: UserService,
  private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
) {
  this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(
    x => (this.currentUser = x)
  );
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCurrentAccount();
    this.currentAccount.map(obj => {
      this.account = obj;
    });
  }

getCurrentAccount() {
    this.userService.getAllUserAccounts().subscribe(
      (data: UserAccount[]) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.currentAccount = data.filter(
          x => x.accountName === this.currentUser.firstName
        );
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.error('Could not retrieve user account ID');
      }
    );
  }
```

I have tried `.map()` and `.forEach()` in my `ngOnInit()` to try and extract that object out from the array and map it to my `account`. I just couldn't seem to get it.

One thing to note however, whenever I use any array methods to try and get the object, my console would throw an error when the page loads:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at ViewAccountPayableComponent.ngOnInit (view-account-payable.component.ts:35)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31909)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44366)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44305)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45327)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45270)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ViewAccountPayableComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45258)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44270)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
```

I want to extract it out because I want to use the attributes in `UserAccount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being that `this.currentAccount` is empty, the data is being retrieved asynchronously and you are trying to use `.map` before the data being retrieved.

Move the assignment part inside the logic as follows,

```
getCurrentAccount() {
    this.userService.getAllUserAccounts().subscribe(
      (data: UserAccount[]) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.currentAccount = data.filter(
          x => x.accountName === this.currentUser.firstName
        );
        this.currentAccount.map(obj => {
         this.account = obj;
        });
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.error('Could not retrieve user account ID');
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the job for you:

```
this.userService.getAllUserAccounts().subscribe(
  (data: UserAccount[]) => {
    console.log(data);
    if (data) {
      this.account = data.find(x => x.accountName === this.currentUser.firstName);
    };
  },
  error => {
    this.alertService.error('Could not retrieve user account ID');
  }
);
```